# How can I hide a div class if there is no output-content available?

Tags: html, css, hide

I'm trying to hide a section (div class) if there's no output string. How do I go about doing this?

`<div class="series">
<b>Series:</b>
<a href="<?php the_field( 'series_link' ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field( 'books_series' ); ?></a>
<?php ?>
</div>`

I'm looking for it to disappear when there's no content available through the series_link.

Comment: Please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it will JS HTML DOM function. Here is a sample code for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

  var str = "";
  var n = str.length;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;

  if (n==0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can identify the string length. If it's zero then set the display value none either block which make visible section if is there any value.

Comment: Hi Sayedur, Thanks for your answer but I'm still struggling to get it to work.

Is this because I always have a static element (the title) so it will always show?